# Malform query when try to delete bulk records

Tags: bulk-delete

I want to delete bulk records from a custom object.

i am reffering below url:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm

and my batch is

```
Account obj = new Account(id="0012800000XRdPgAAL");
delete obj;
```

> InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected
>   token: Account

Can any one please help me , how can i delete multiple records from a custom object using API.

Comment: can you give some more info? The link you are referencing is using curl to create bulk jobs while you seem to be writing apex code...

Comment: Try replacing "" (double quotes) with Single quotes ' ' @sfdcweb